# PySpark Error - SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark job that reads data into a dataframe and tokenizes a column as a part of the transformations. I have the follwoing:

`Main.py` - reads configs and creates sparkSession

`Extractor.py` - reads the data from source and returns the dataframe to `main.py`

`Transformer.py` - in case there are any tranfsormaions required, the `main.py` sends the dataframe to `Transformer` where tokenization is performed along with other transformations and returns the dataframe to `Main.py`

I don't have any issues with doing other transformations like casting columns, but whenever I run the job with tokenization set to true, I am getting weird error:

```
Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-506
```

here is my `Transformer.py` tokenization code:

```
def perform_transformations(self, df):
    if 'tokenization' in config:
        self.log.info("sending to tokenization")
        self.log.info(tokenize_cols)
        df = self.tokenize_data_from_snowflake(df)

def tokenize_data_from_snowflake(self, data):
    self.logger.info(f"Begin tokenize process for data")
    for column in tokenize_cols:
        self.logger.info(f"processing for column: {column}")
        data = self.get_tokenized_df(column, data=data)
        self.logger.info(data.schema)
    self.logger.info(f"Tokenize process for data completed successfully")
    return data

def chunks(self, iterable, chunk_size):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for chunk in iter(lambda: list(islice(iterator, chunk_size)), []):
        yield chunk

def get_tokenized_df(self, column, data):
    if data.count() == 0:
        return data
    schema = data.schema

    def map_partitions(partition):
        for current_group in self.chunks(partition, 20):
            self.logger.info(f"printing column: {column}")
            self.logger.info(f"printing currentGroup: {current_group}")
            clear_text_batch = []
            tokenizer_value_map = {}
            for row in current_group:
                clear_text_batch.append(
                        row["A"][:32]
                        if column == "A"
                        else row[column]
                    )
            self.logger.info(f"clear_text_batch: {clear_text_batch}")
            if len(clear_text_batch) > 0:
                # Ensure you are calling the tokenizer with the correct column
                tokenizer_value_map.update(self.call_tokenizer(column, clear_text_batch))
                self.logger.info(tokenizer_value_map)
                self.logger.info("returned to map partitions")

                for i, row in enumerate(current_group):
                    current_group[i] = self.process_row(row, column, tokenizer_value_map)
            yield current_group
        # print(f"updated_rows: {current_group}")

    return data.rdd.mapPartitions(map_partitions).flatMap(lambda x: x).toDF(schema)

def update_row(self, row, column, value):
    row_dict = row.asDict()
    row_dict[column] = value
    return Row(**row_dict)

def process_row(self, row, column, tokenizer_value_map):
    self.logger.info("in process_row")
    clear_text_value = row[column]
    tokenized_value = tokenizer_value_map.get(
        clear_text_value[:32] if column == "A" else clear_text_value,
        "No Token Received"
    )
    self.logger.info(f"values -> {clear_text_value} : {tokenized_value}")
    return self.update_row(row, "TOKENIZED_" + column, tokenized_value)

def call_tokenizer(self, column_name, cleartext_data):
    #call tokenizer service code
```

the logic is to take the existing values of column that needs to be tokenized, call a tokenizer service and then update the row with the tokenized value. the bulk of this logic is in `get_tokenized_df` method. the error is being thrown at

```
return data.rdd.mapPartitions(map_partitions).flatMap(lambda x: x).toDF(schema)
```

I had no issue with running this logic before when `Transformer.py` itself was reading the data into the dataframe and sending it to another class for transformation. I am seeing this error after I did some refactoring of the code. I did check the Jira page mentioned in the error: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063 but couldn't figure out anything from it. So I am not sure how I should be debugging/resolving this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: does `call_tokenizer` have any UDFs?

Comment: @samkart it doesn't have any UDFs. it uses http session to do a post to tokenizer service and get the response. It uses the response to update the rows with tokenized values.